# Remove common value from two different array of dictionaries

Tags: swift4.2

I have 2 array of dictionary:

```
serverContactsDict = [["name": “Miya”,”number": “4178547852”],
                      [“name": “Simon”,”number": “2458741458”],
                      ["name": “Pio”,”number": “7414785236”]]
```

and

```
phoneContactsDict = [["name": “Miya”,”number": “4178547852”],
                     [“name": “Simon”,”number": “2458741458”],
                     ["name": “Pio”,”number": “7414785236”],
                     ["name": “Kayle”,”number": “2547859632”],
                     ["name": “Hoya”,”number": “7485965841”]]
```

and

```
DesiredDict = [["name": “Kayle”,”number": “2547859632”],
               ["name": “Hoya”,”number": “7485965841”]]
```

Tried so much but doesn't get the desired result.

Comment: ` for i in 0..<serverContactsDict.count {
            let d1 = serverContactsDict[i] as NSDictionary
            let n1 = d1.value(forKey: "number") as! String
            print("N1:: ", n1)
            for j in 0..<phoneContactsDict.count {
                let d2 = phoneContactsDict[j] as NSDictionary
                let n2 = d2.value(forKey: "number") as! String
                print("N2 :: ", n2)
     
                if n1 == n2{
                    print("Matched :: ", n1)
                    matchedNumberArray.append(n1)
                    phoneContactsDict.remove(at: j)}} }

Comment: got error: Fatal error: Index out of range

@ line let d2 = phoneContactsDict[j] as NSDictionary

Comment: Resolved for now

Answer (score 0):

```
let desiredDict = phoneContactsDict.filter {
  let dict = $0
  return !serverContactsDict.contains{ dict == $0 }
}
```